# "... of the major" or "... major", what's the difference?

Tags: meaning, expressions, differences

I am just looking at a text review and we are unable to agree on what would be the best way of saying between the examples in the title.

What is the difference between this:

> this study focuses on the thought of [...], three **of the** major representatives of the ...

And this

> this study focuses on the thought of [...], three major representatives of the ...

Any help?

Comment: As far as I can tell the first "of the" can be removed without impacting meaning or grammar.  Brevity is it's own reward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is more concise and therefore better unless you wish to stress that there are other major representatives of the [...] not discussed in the study.